# I want to add Values in 2nd dropdown list after checking tht selective index of 1st frop down in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

Basically I have a form  which has 2 drop downs. In the 1st drop down I am selecting City category. When the city is selected I want to update the 2nd drop down values in correspondence to  1st value choosen in 1st drop down. I have done like this,
This adds  the value in the 1st Drop Down:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim s As String = "connection String"
    sqlconn = New SqlConnection(s)


    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("select DISTINCT City from usrRegister_aunthentication", sqlconn)
    If sqlconn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sqlconn.Open()
    End If

    dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dataReader.Read
        Citydropdown.Items.Add(dataReader("City").ToString())
    End While

    dataReader.Close()

    If sqlconn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
        sqlconn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now suppose I selected a city, it should update the 2nd dropdown for that I have done this:

```
Protected Sub Citydropdown_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Citydropdown.Load
        Dim CityID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Citydropdown.SelectedValue.ToString())
        FillStates(CityID)

    End Sub


 Private Sub FillStates(ByVal CityID As Integer)
        Dim strConn As String = "server=.;database=Opex;integrated security=true;pooling=false;"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "sql statement"
        Dim objDs As New DataSet()
        Dim dAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        con.Open()
        dAdapter.Fill(objDs)
        con.Close()
        If objDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            'HallsDropDown.DataSource = objDs.Tables(0)
            'HallsDropDown.DataTextField = "Theater_Name"
            'HallsDropDown.DataBind()
            'HallsDropDown.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--")
        Else
            Response.Write("No states found")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

My XML for this is as follows. Can anyone help me to add values in the 2nd drop down by selecting the index from 1st dropdown?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table style="height:50px;">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Label Text="Select your City" runat="server" ID="lblcity"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="Citydropdown"   runat="server" />
    </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:label runat="server" id="lblHals" Text="Select Your Halls" ></asp:label>  
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="HallsDropDown" runat="server" />
    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AVD i have updated the question  Could u please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You will need to turn on autopostback and tell it what to execute when the selected index of the dropdownlist changes:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Citydropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Citydropdown_Load">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Also, make sure you add a postback check in the Page_Load method so you don't reload the city dropdownlist every time:

```
If Not IsPostBack
    Dim s As String = "connection String"
    sqlconn = New SqlConnection(s)


    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("select DISTINCT City from usrRegister_aunthentication", sqlconn)
    If sqlconn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sqlconn.Open()
    End If

    dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dataReader.Read
        Citydropdown.Items.Add(dataReader("City").ToString())
    End While

    dataReader.Close()

    If sqlconn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
        sqlconn.Close()
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use such cascade is to use a webservice to bind your dropdown and call that webservice through you javascript/jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#ddlCity").change(function() {
            $("#ddlState").html("");
            var CityID = $("#ddlCity option:selected").val();

            $.getJSON('ServerResponse.aspx?CityID=' + CityID, function(states) {

                $.each(states, function() {

                    $("#ddlState").append($("<option></option>").val(this['StateCode']).html(this['StateName']));

                });
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Link you can refer to:
http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/niladribiswas/archive/2011/07/29/cascading-drop-down-example-country-state-and-city-in-jquery.aspx